# git rebase: only --root shows commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am on branch master. When I do `git rebase -i --root master` I can see every commit ever made in the repository and rebase. However, when I do a `git rebase -i master` or a `git rebase -i origin/master`, I get:

> noop
>
> Rebase fa2874e..4a271fe onto fa2874e (       1 TODO item(s))

When I pick a specific commit to rebase onto, I can rebase, e.g., `git rebase -i d0738d9d076cc64565659920b8cf0405fa8f6f4e` works.

But in other projects I have worked on, I am positive* that `git rebase -i master` works without picking a specific commit and shows the delta between all commits on the current branch and master.

What is going on here? Do I have something wrong with remotes?

Comment: May I ask what do you intend to do when you try to rebase `master` when the checked out branch also happens to be `master`? I believe as there isn't any new commit in the new base (`master`), the operation is expendable - which is probably the reason git labels it as a `noop`. You may want to try `git rebase -i master~n` where n is the number of latest commits that you want to change, if that's the objective here.

Comment: So sometimes in early stage projects that I start, I rewrite master's history before releasing it to other people. For example if I have commits A B C D, where B and C are messy and D kinda fixes everything, I will rebase and squish everything down to make it look like I knew what I was doing from the start. Then people just see A D or maybe even just A. Essentially, I use rebase to make my time series of commits make it look like I knew what should have been done from the start, where in reality I learned what I wanted later.

Comment: I see. You can probably try `git rebase HEAD~3` or `git rebase master~4` variations of the command.

Comment: @NishantShreshth git rebase master~4 works; if you post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Alright. But I think I should have included `-i` in my last comment. Was it not `git rebase -i master~4` (with `-i` flag) that solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of `git rebase -i HEAD~n` or `git rebase -i master~n` flavours of the command.

`n` refers to number of commits that you want to modify.